# Rewritten url not being changed in url bar

Tags: php, .htaccess

I made a page which loads content dynamically depending on the alias that was sent. This works fine, but the url stays uglified.

Example:
https://website.nl/aanbieding.php?alias=this-is-the-alias

But I want:
https://website.nl/aanbieding/this-is-the-alias.html

htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^aanbieding/(.*).html /aanbieding.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

I got the exact same htacess rule for another page, and that one works like I want.

This one:

```
RewriteRule ^diensten/(.*).html dienst.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

When I click from the page itself to another page (same file on the server but different loaded content) the url turns into what I want. Only when I open it from an email template the url stays ugly.

I link from the mail template like this:

```
<a href="https://www.website.nl/aanbieding/this-is-the-alias.html" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank">Bekijk aanbieding</a>
```

Why is the url changing into my example?

Comment: Try to add [L, QSA] to the rule, that will append the query string.

Comment: What are you asking? The question sounds like a misunderstanding that you think putting in the old URL should redirect to the new one, which isn't what rewriting does. Are you saying going to `https://website.nl/aanbieding/this-is-the-alias.html` doesn't work, or you're just confused that `https://website.nl/aanbieding.php?alias=this-is-the-alias` isn't redirecting (which there's no reason it should).

Comment: RewriteRule ^aanbieding/([^/]*)\.html$ /aanbieding.php?alias=$1 [L]

Comment: @JonStirling No I find it weird that `https://website.nl/aanbieding/this-is-the-alias.html` redirects to `https://website.nl/aanbieding.php?alias=this-is-the-alias` only when I navigate there from my email template.

Comment: @twan if that's really happening, it's not by anything of the stuff you've given us.

Comment: @MathieuDormeval This doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @anubhava It stays the same. Only when I go there from the anchor tag I posted in my question the url is changed. The only difference is, on my website I got a base tag which is `<base href="https://website.nl/">` so on my website I link like: aanbieding/this-is-the-alias.html and from my mail I use the full url.

Comment: @anubhava I have the same issue in incognito and different browsers.

Comment: Have you got a RewriteBase / on your htacess ?

Comment: I found out what it was. From my email I had www in the url, and on the site itself I don't use www in the urls. This was the fix. No idea why it changes the url if I add www. at the beginning though...